# Python class variable overwrites all instance variables when using slots - why?

Tags: python, class, syntax

I've noticed some strange behavior I don't fully understand. I am using **slots** in a class for performance reasons. How come it is so easy to damage all class instances by a simple class variable assignment?

```
class Person:
    __slots__ = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


p1 = Person('mc')
p2 = Person('pp')

# The nasty thing here:
Person.name = 'hacked'

print(p1)
print(p2)
```

As a result, all instances have their 'name' attribute overwritten. Shouldn't it be prevented by the interpreter? It is the case when you want to explicitly define a class variable of the same name as used in a slot.

I am a bit puzzled as it looks way too prone to even accidental damage.

Answer (score 1):

You're disrupting the implementation of `__slots__` when you do:

```
Person.name = 'hacked'
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots):

> `__slots__` are implemented at the class level by creating descriptors (Implementing Descriptors) for each variable name. As a result, class attributes cannot be used to set default values for instance variables defined by `__slots__`; otherwise, the class attribute would overwrite the descriptor assignment.

Which means `Person.name` was actually a `<class 'member_descriptor'>` when the class was created. After your 'hack', it became a normal `str`. You can check this by printing the `type(Person.name)` before & after your 'hack'.

`__slots__` changes class behavior in subtle ways, so read the docs carefully before using it.

Comment: I know I am abusing it (I don't do it in normal code, this was just an experiment), I was just surprised the interpreter allowed that. If you want to define a class variable explicitly (in the class definition) you get an error. I'd expect similar behavior when overriding a slots variable.